# How to convert 2 bytes to Int16 in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

**There is a method in bitconverter class in java which has a method called toInt16**

*But in dart i am unable to cast short as Int16*

```java
public static short toInt16( byte[] bytes, int index )
                            throws Exception {
        if ( bytes.length != 8 )
            throw new Exception( "The length of the byte array must be at least 8 bytes long." );
        return (short) ( ( 0xff & bytes[index] ) << 8 | ( 0xff & bytes[index + 1] ) << 0 );
 }
```

can someone help me with this conversion to dart language ?

**Here is the updated dart version of answer that i followed using the ByteData class suggested by emerssso and this works for me**

```dart
int toInt16(Uint8List byteArray, int index)
{
    ByteBuffer buffer = byteArray.buffer;
    ByteData data = new ByteData.view(buffer);
    int short = data.getInt16(index, Endian.little);
    return short;
}
```

*I had to specifically set **Endian.little** because originally **getInt16** method is set to **BigEndian** but my byte data was in former order*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for one of the methods on the ByteData class available in `dart:typed_data`. Wrap your byte array in a `ByteData` via `ByteData.view()` and then you can arbitrarily access bytes as a specified type. You could then do i.e. `byteData.getInt16(index);`.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html